# connecting shiny webapp to oracle database

Tags: r, oracle, shiny, odbc, shinyapps

I am building a shiny web app with r studio.

Now I want data from my companys oracle sql server on it.

On my computer, I can easily establish a connection via odbc, because I have the driver on my computer. With code like this:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "name", UID="uid", PWD= "pwd")
```

Now, is this connection possible when uploaded to shinyapps.io?

Also, with this code, I can only connect inside our companys vpn-network. How do I establish a connection from outside? I tried adding host and port, but that does not work.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Have a look at the docs https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html#accessing-databases-with-odbc

Comment: Unless someone open your company's firewall, or you use some kind of gateway, you will not be able to reach your company database from the outside. Can you use a cloud database like Oracle Free Tier and push data to it from your company db?